# Single string or list of strings in a method

Tags: python

I have run into this several times.  I'm dealing with a lot of methods that can accept a list of strings.  Several times I have accidentally passed a single string and it gets broken apart into a list and each character is used, which isn't the desired behavior.

```
def test(a,b):
    x = []
    x.extend(a)
    x.extend(b)
    return x

x = [1,2,3,4]
```

What I don't want to happen:

```
test(x,'test')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 't', 'e', 's', 't']
```

I have to resort to a strange syntax:

```
test(x,['list'])
```

I would like these to work implicitly:

```
test(x,'list')
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'test']

test(x,['one', 'two', 'three'])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

I really feel like there's a "pythonic" way to do this or something involving duck typing, but I don't see it.  I know I could use isinstance() to check if it's a string, but I feel like there's a better way.

**Edit**:  I'm using python 2.4.3

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to re-interpret the expected behavior of `list.extend()` to overcome problems related to *accidental* input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, may this is easy way:

```
>>> def a(*args):
...     x=[]
...     for i in args:
...             if '__iter__' in dir(i):
...                     x+=list(i)
...             else:
...                     x.append(i)
...     return x
... 
>>> a(1,2,3,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a(1,2,[3,4])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a(1,2,[3,4],'123')
[1, 2, 3, 4, '123']
>>> a(1,2,[3,4],'123', 1231, (1, 2, 3, 4))
[1, 2, 3, 4, '123', 1231, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I didn't even think to peek at dir() to see if it contains __iter__.  This is great.

Comment: On python3 this would fail since a string has '__iter__'

Comment: For 2/3 compatibility, use `six`, which provides a cross-version way to check for string types: `if isinstance(value, six.string_types): value = [value]`

Answer (score 13):

Use this

```
def test( x, *args ):
```

Now you can do

```
test( x, 'one' )
```

and

```
test( x, 'one', 'two' )
```

and

```
test( x, *['one', 'two',] )
```

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: You're right.  Unit testing is more important than this level of syntatic nonsense.  However, I figured I'd go with the "no unit testing" approach, since that seemed to be implied by the question.

Comment: @NullUserException: Downvotes mean "this is wrong" or "this isn't helpful in the given context".  They don't mean "I stylistically disagree".  This answer is certainly helpful.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah, I removed the downvote. But I am still not a fan of this approach.

Comment: +1 Using API design to remove ambiguity is a very reasonable and clean solution.

Answer (score 9):

I'm sorry to say it but this really is one of the few cases where using `isinstance()` makes sense. However one of the other answers that suggests testing for `list` is doing it backwards: `str` (and for Python 2.x `unicode`) are the anomalous types so those are the ones you test for:

```
def test(a,b):
    x = []
    if isinstance(b, str): b = [b]
    x.extend(a)
    x.extend(b)
    return x
```

or for Python 2.x test `isinstance(b, basestring)`.

Comment: I have several instances where I've passed an argument where the list is a list of dictionary keys (as strings).  Passing 'test' would try a lookup for mydict['t'], mydict['e'], etc.  Maybe isinstance is best for the above example.  It's certainly the easiest way to see the intent.

Comment: Going further, the API should offer a default argument so that the caller can decide which iterable types are to be considered atomic.  That avoids hardwiring the behavior.  def test(a, b, atomic=(basestring, buffer)): ...

Answer (score 3):

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

In my opinion, your first example is explicit. It takes two values and processes them in well-understood ways. Although it "feels" a little strange to new Python programmers, it behaves just like expect. `list.extend` accepts lists, so it treats strings like a list of chars.

Your proposal alters the semantics of `list.extend` to be equivalent to `list.append`, but *only* when dealing with strings. That would be a real surprise to someone who *wants* your function to treat your strings as lists of chars and who would then have to call it like `test(x,list('test'))`.

You *can* do what you're asking, but please don't. :-)

Comment: Agreed. It's better to not impose an explicit type requirement on the input if it can be avoided.

Comment: I think that pod2metra's response satisfies this, don't you agree?  It utilizes the `__iter__` attribute and doesn't enforce any specific type.

Comment: I don't have any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

A little tweak to pod2metra's answer enables the function to handle all levels of annidation:

```
>>> def b(*args):
...     x=[]
...     for i in args:
...             if '__iter__' in dir(i):
...                     x += b(*i)
...             else:
...                     x.append(i)
...     return x
... 
>>> b(1, (2, (3, 4)))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Instead with the function 'a' you had:

```
>>> a(1, (2, (3, 4)))
[1, 2, (3, 4)]
```

I know it was not in the intentions of the original question, but maybe this generalization can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test the type of the parameter:

```
def test(a,b):
    x = a if isinstance(a, list) else [a]
    x += b if isinstance(b, list) else [b]
    return x
```

Comment: -1 This is exactly what the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: Also, I'm using python 2.4.3 (blame RedHat the the lower version).  That kind of use of "if" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user179256 It doesn't. This syntax was added on 2.5

Comment: I just noticed that the above code seems to modify the variable 'a' because of the use of x = a when a is a list.  I think when x = [a] is used, that doesn't modify a outside of the method.